# Filling between two B-spline curves

Tags: graphics, splines, filling

I am trying to fill the space between two curves (curve1 and curve2) I generated since long but unable to do so. Can some one help on this please. The following is the code snippet.

```
pts1 = {{55.78, 57}, {23.03, 63.18}, {2.3, 59.21}, {0, 46.85}, {0, 
    35.18}, {28.57, 35.03}, {49.39, 35.03}, {62.19, 24.39}, {52.4, 
    7.4}, {29, 9}, {0, 10}};

curve1 = Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[pts1], Green, Line[pts1], Red, 
   Point[pts1]}]
pts2 = {{55.78, 50}, {23.03, 56.18}, {7.3, 54.21}, {7, 46.85}, {5.0, 
    40.18}, {28.57, 42.03}, {55.56, 38.50}, {69.19, 24.39}, {57.4, 
    2.4}, {29, 2}, {0.5, 3}};
curve2 = Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[pts2], Green, Line[pts2], Red, 
   Point[pts2]}]
pts3 = {{55.78, 57}, {55.78, 50}};
pts4 = {{0, 10}, {0.5, 3}};
curve3 = Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[pts3], Green, Line[pts3], Red, 
   Point[pts3]}]
curve4 = Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[pts4], Green, Line[pts4], Red, 
   Point[pts4]}]
Show[curve1, curve2, curve3, curve4, 
 Filling -> {{{1} -> {2}}, {Yellow}}]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Graphics[{
   Yellow, FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve /@ {pts1, pts4, Reverse@pts2, pts3}}],
   Green, Line[Join[pts1, pts4, Reverse@pts2, pts3]],
   Red, Point[Join[pts1, pts2, pts3, pts4]]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi March...Amazing...it Worked..!! Thanks a ton.. :D

Comment: Is there any place to get a better S and other alphabets....I am looking for a better shape...or is it only on trial and error basis we figure out the points?

Answer (score 6):

```
Graphics[
 {
  Yellow,
  FilledCurve@{
    BSplineCurve[
     Join[pts1, Reverse@pts2]
     , SplineClosed -> True
     ]
    }
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]